# Xamarin forms set max height image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been searching for this but can't find anything.

I wanna to set a max height to an image. It could be inside some other element or not.

I don't wanna that image to be with a static size.

I apreciate any help

Comment: There is no universal answer. Xamarin layout is complex and it isn't easy way to set anything to be 100% in the fixed size (in your case maximum size) without knowing the context. So you must show your current code first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no max height property in Xamarin.Forms, and it is not supported with the CSS styling either. There is already an enhancement request to add a max height property: https://www.google.com/search?q=Xamarin.+Forms+maximum+height&oq=Xamarin.+Forms+maximum+height&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6714j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

However, you could monitor the `SizeChanged` event for the `Image` and check the height and reset it as necessary, e.g.:

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="imagename.png" />
```

C# code behind:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        image.SizeChanged += (sender, e) => {
            if (image.Height > 50)
                image.HeightRequest = 50;
        };
    }
```

Comment: In many cases (e.g. if Image VerticalOptions is Fill) this won't work, and actually I would expect that this won't work in his app, though it might work in some situations yes.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that after I posted it. Another option might be a custom renderer, but setting the height in a custom renderer for the Image won't update the layout for the surrounding elements based on the new image height.

Comment: Will this event (SizeChanged) automatically unsubscribed or do you have to do it manually? When would you unsubscribe it?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your VerticalOptions to something other than fill then the HeightRequest property is used e.g.

```
Image fileIcon = new Image
{
   Source = "icon",
   HeightRequest = 50,
   VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};
```